# jquery tipsy is broken

Tags: javascript, jquery

HELP! I need help setting up tipsy I had it working earlier but now its not working here is my website http://timothy.techbytbone.com/

js:

```
$(function () {
$('.info').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'Click on me to run the color animation.'});
$('.info2').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'Also you get the Invite feature under the Menu.'});
$('.info3').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'Bible application.'});
$('.info4').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'White board application.'});
$('.info5').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'Pac Man game.'});
$('.info6').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'Pong game.'});
$('.info7').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'Space Invaders game.'});
$('.info8').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'Click on a button to change the website color.'});
$('.info9').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'w', fallback:'Page views counter'});
$('.info10').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'No way! you found the portal to my secret site!'});
$('.info11').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'Click me to see the time.'});
$('.info12').tipsy({fade:true, gravity:'s', fallback:'Click me to open a popup whiteboard.'});
});
```

links: (including jquery and my js file link)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/libs/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/tipsy.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/tipsy-docs.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
<script src="../js/mainjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="../jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
```

Comment: It would help to tell us what you have tried. A lot of people won't be willing to help someone who's not willing to troubleshoot himself a little before asking for help. :)

Comment: What doesn't work? Anything in the console? Why two versions of jQuery (seems a bad idea)?

Comment: start removing things you added until you get it back to the version that is working. you can figure out which file is causing the issue

Comment: i have tried to get it working for 3 hours of none stop troubleshotting

Comment: i didn't see i was loading 2 versions can you point that out?

Comment: Like which one's i am loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We already answered this I was loading 2 versions of jquery which was a problem...